# Querying for objects. "q" query does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

With the Javascript API, I'm doing this:

```
client.search({
    index:'530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58',
    type:'532a2b28495c533e5eaeb020',
    q:'slide'
},function (error,response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    if(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

I want to search any document containing the word 'slide'.

The query returns no hits.

However, if I type this:

```
http://server:9200/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58/532a2b28495c533e5eaeb020/_search?pretty=true
```

Into a browser, I get hits.

What am I doing wrong?

More information:

---

The javascript query returns this:

```
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2014-05-20T00:19:04Z
  starting request { method: 'POST',
    path: '/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58/532a2b28495c533e5eaeb020/_search',
    query: { q: 'slide' } }


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2014-05-20T00:19:04Z
  -> POST http:/server:9200/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58/532a2b28495c533e5eae
b020/_search?q=slide

  <- 200
  {
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
    }
  }

Elasticsearch INFO: 2014-05-20T00:19:04Z
  Request complete

{ took: 3,
  timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 },
  hits: { total: 0, max_score: null, hits: [] } }
```

I'm indexing my information like this:

```
client.index({
    index:data2.name,
    type:data2.files[i].author,
        id:data2.files[i]._id.toString(),
    body:data2.files[i]
},function(err,resp){
    if(err){console.log(err)};
        if(resp){console.log(resp)};
});
```

### Edit:

The entirety of my node.js app is this:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'server:9200',
    log:'trace'
});

client.search({
    q:'slide'   
},function (error,response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    if(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

With the exception that `server` is replaced with a real ip address.

My node app is running locally, and it's connecting to an EC2 instance which has ports 80, 443, 9200, and 9300 open.

### EDIT2:

I changed my app to this:

```
client.search({

},function (error,response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    if(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And I got everything. However, how do I specify a query, and yet have it work?

### EDIT3:

The node.js elasticsearch module I'm using is v2.1.6
The API I'm looking at is for something called v1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run queries by replacing

`q:'slide'`

With

`query:'slide'`

So either the version of elasticsearch that I have doesn't match [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search), or the documentation is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that changing `q:` to `query:` is doing what you want? Using query doesn't return filtered results, but using `q:` does.

Comment: For me, `q` doesn't return anything at all, so something is better than nothing.